# Can a regular expression itself be parsed with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, parsing, regular-language

I am reading the code of a regular expression parser, and start to wonder if the syntax of regular expression is itself regular, and can be expressed with another (quite complicated) regular expression?

```
rere = "" # the regular expression of regular language
match1 = re.match(rere, "[a-z]+@[a-z]+.com") # True
match2 = re.match(rere, ")az[") # False
```

I don't see any recursive structure in regular expression syntax, so I think maybe this is doable?

If it is, what does the expression look like?
If not, why?

Comment: No. You need context-free grammar to parse regular expression. Nested parentheses can't be parsed with (theoretical) regular expression.

Comment: Yes, nested parentheses. I forgot about that. But if I don't support group inside group, would the answer be different?

Comment: @NeoWang: Then what you have is weaker than regular expression. i.e. there are languages where regular expression/regular grammar can described, but not your grammar.

Comment: Actually, you can match nested parentheses with regex, but only in some regex flavors. Your example code is Python, and its regex engine does not support [recursive behavior](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#balanced)/[balanced constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html). However, there is no magical regex that will "parse them all".

Comment: @stribizhev: Those flavor are not strictly "regular" in the theoretical sense, but if the question specifically refers to real world "regex" engines, then I guess it's possible for some flavors.

Comment: This may be off topic... Why are most regex parsers hand written? Why not write its context free grammar and use a parser generator?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot parse nested parentheses with a regular expression because you would need infinite state to do so. So the answer is no. What you are looking for is called [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).